# Get comma separated string from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON in JS.

```
{
   "url":"http://example.com/main.aspx",
   "report_template_id":"1",
   "interval_secs":"86400",
   "analysis_type":"lite",
   "email":"rokumar@example.com",
   "alerts":["num_domains", "med_load_time", "avg_load_time", "tot_req"]
}
```

I want the list of alerts to be removed and replaced with comma separated values as follows.

```
{
   "url":"http://example.com/main.aspx",
    "report_template_id":"1",
    "interval_secs":"86400",
    "analysis_type":"lite",
    "email":"rokumar@example.com",
    "alerts":"num_domains,med_load_time,avg_load_time,tot_req"
}
```

Comment: the output you said you need is not a valid json. Do you really want to break the json.

Comment: The second JSON is the expected output, I want to remove list of alerts and simply have comma separated values.

Comment: Is it correct to assume you made a typo and what you want is *one* string instead of several comma-separated strings?

Comment: why do you want to convert a JSON array (with is supported by the JSON format) to a comma separated string? I can't think of a good reason to do it. It would be great if you step few steps back and ask the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just adding all the steps:-

1). Taking your JSON in a variable.

```
data = {"url":"http://example.com/main.aspx","report_template_id":"1","interval_secs":"86400","analysis_type":"lite","email":"rokumar@example.com","alerts":["num_domains","med_load_time","avg_load_time","tot_req"]};
```

2). Parse JSON data to object. **Assuming the JSON is a string initially do a `typeof(data)` to be clear.**

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

3) Change list of alerts to comma separated values

```
data.alerts = data.alerts.join(',');
```

4) Convert back to string

```
data = JSON.stringify(data)
```

So data will look like

```
{
    "url": "http://example.com/main.aspx",
    "report_template_id": "1",
    "interval_secs": "86400",
    "analysis_type": "lite",
    "email": "rokumar@example.com",
    "alerts": "num_domains,med_load_time,avg_load_time,tot_req"
}
```

**Note:-** If you will just say `join()` then also it will work, because default delimiter is `,` only, just to clarify I have given that.

Comment: `data.alerts.concat()` would also do the job.

Comment: This throws an error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined`

Comment: @user567797 `data` here is just whatever the name of your variable that holds the json is. Make sure you use the right varriable name.

Comment: If I do an `alert(data.alerts);` it gives me undefined whereas an `alert(data);` gives me the whole json. Somejhow the querying is wrong I guess

Comment: You have to parse it first. Right now `data` is string.

Comment: @user567797 just do a `typeof(data)` and if it says string do a `data=JSON.parse(data)` it will convert data to object from string.

Comment: How to convert it back to a string . I tried JSON.stringify(data), but it prints [object][object]

Comment: no need to parse data if it's a js object
`var data = {"url":"http://in.strawberrynet.com/main.aspx","report_template_id":"1","interval_secs":"86400","analysis_type":"lite","email":"rokumar@gmail.com","alerts":["num_domains","med_load_time","avg_load_time","tot_req"]};`

Comment: you should parse data if 
`var data = '{"url":"http://in.strawberrynet.com/main.aspx","report_template_id":"1","interval_secs":"86400","analysis_type":"lite","email":"rokumar@gmail.com","alerts":["num_domains","med_load_time","avg_load_time","tot_req"]}'`